# Change Numeric Value of a Slider

Tags: button, javafx, slider

I'm writing a program with two sliders, which values are displayed in respective labels (counter1 and counter2). Slider2 is bound to slider1, but can also move independently. After moving slider1 (and as a result slider2), I want to be able to press a button that will do two things:

1. Lock in the value of slider1
2. Change the value of counter2 so that it starts counting at zero no matter where slider2 is (i.e. - even though the slider may be at -10, counter2 shows zero. Then -9 would be 1, -8 would be 2, etc.)

Here's the relevant code I have so far:

```
public CreateSliders() {

    Slider slider1 = new Slider();
    slider1.setMin(-30);
    slider1.setMax(30);
    slider1.setMinWidth(300);
    slider1.setValue(0);
    slider1.setShowTickLabels(true);
    slider1.setShowTickMarks(true);
    slider1.setMajorTickUnit(10);
    slider1.setMinorTickCount(1);
    slider1.setBlockIncrement(1);

    Label counter1 = new Label(Double.toString(slider1.getValue()));

    Button btn1 = new Button("Lock");

    HBox counter1Hbox = new HBox(counter1, btn1);
    counter1Hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle (ActionEvent event) {
            counter2.setText("0.0");                
        }
    });

    Slider slider2 = new Slider();
    slider2.setMin(-30);
    slider2.setMax(30);
    slider2.setMinWidth(300);
    slider2.setValue(0);
    slider2.setShowTickLabels(true);
    slider2.setShowTickMarks(true);
    slider2.setMajorTickUnit(10);
    slider2.setMinorTickCount(1);
    slider2.setBlockIncrement(1);

    Label counter2 = new Label(Double.toString(slider2.getValue()));

    HBox counter2Hbox = new HBox(counter2);
    counter2Hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    slider1.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            counter1.setText(String.format("%.0f", newValue));
            slider2.valueProperty().set(slider2.valueProperty().get() + newValue.doubleValue() - oldValue.doubleValue());
        }
    });

    slider2.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            counter2.setText(String.format("%.0f", newValue));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For questions such as this, it is usually better to ask two questions, rather than two questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lock the slider position you can use:

```
ToggleButton btnLock = new ToggleButton("Lock");
btnLock.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, b, b1) -> 
   {
      slider1.setMouseTransparent(b1));
      //or
      slider.setDisable(b1));
   });

//or
slider1.disableProperty().bind(btnLock.selectedProperty());
```

For point 2:

```
private double lastSliderPosition;

public void createSliders(){
        //initialize sliders 

        ToggleButton btnLock = new ToggleButton("Lock");
        btnLock.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, b, b1) -> {
            slider1.setDisable(b1);

            if (b1) {
                slider2.valueProperty().unbind();
            } else {
                slider2.valueProperty().bind(slider1.valueProperty());
            }
        });

        slider2.valueProperty().bind(slider1.valueProperty());

        slider2.valueProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
            if (!slider2.isValueChanging()) {
                lastSliderValue = (double) t1;
            }

            if (btnLock.isSelected()) {
                counter2.setText(String.format("%.0f", t.doubleValue() - lastSliderValue));
            } else {
                counter2.setText(String.format("%.0f", t1));
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Sweet! That worked perfectly. Now if anyone can help me with my second need.

Comment: I just tried to give you an up-vote, but something popped up saying I don't have enough points.

Comment: Where is the lastSliderValue coming from? How is it initiated?

Comment: `lastSliderPosition` is a double field you create, to buffer the slider position. It's value is assigned in the listener for `slider2.valueProperty()`

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I typed it in just as you have it here and looking at it, the logic makes sense. But when I move the second slider, counter2 still shows the slider number value, not the reset number value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, I had another action handler that I neglected to get rid of. It was overriding what you'd put here. Thanks so much for your help!